# Could you help me about Websocket and Real Live Data Strem for Grid

Tags: node.js, html, datatable, websocket, socket.io

I have no any experience about Node.js and Websocket.

I checked socket.io and I did example chat . It's working very well .

Now I wonder how can i do like as socket.io CHAT sample but I need to do DATA STREAM GRID.

For example; I have FOREX data feed and I want to REAL LIVE UPDATE on my HTML5 web site .

There is any example for that ?

socket.io chat really so good and looks like powerfully but I don't know how do ot from them DATA TABLE.

I checked some JQuery plugins but they are not working like as CHAT example. Not real live data I can say.

I want also some CSS manipalation on HTML side , when price down or when price up.

Please help me if you know about these things .

Thank you.

Comment: I have no any code...

Im asking where can I start, there is any good sample for REAL LIVE DATA UPDATE. ( push data from server)

I checked some Jquery plugins but they are not working like as CHAT . 

They are checking data every 3-5 sec. 

I need - when data changing on server side, directly changed on HTML5 too. Like as CHAT on Socket.io

Answer (score 0):

If you need to transform your data on the stream, perhaps you could use my node.js module called [Scramjet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet). It could allow you to modify the data on the fly, before pushing them to your page via socket.io. For example if you like to compress the data a little

```js
const io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);
yourForexStream.pipe(new scramjet.DataStream)
    .filter((forexItem) => typeof forexItem.tick !== "undefined") 
       // don't send heartbeats, just ticks
    .map((forexItem) => forexItem.tick) 
       // just send the tick data
    .on("data", (tick) => io.emit("tick", tick)); 
       // broadcast it to socket.io
```